# What is the Radroute bicycle path?

Tags: germany, italy, bicycles

I've seen signs (like the one below in Southern Tyrol) in street view of "Radroute" bicycle paths around Germany but haven't been able to find any information in English. The signpost below seems like it is part of a decent bicycle path going for at least 50km. What is Radroute?

[image: streetview image from South Tyrol]

Comment: Maybe this is obvious to you, but it's worth stating: "Radroute" is the German word for "bicycle path", not the name of that specific path.

Comment: This is in or near Reschen in the Italian Province Southern Tyrol, Alto Adige, Suedtirol. It's an autonmous province with strong ties to Austria and has therefore two official languages: Italian and German. Hence all the signs are in both languages. Radroute simply means bicycle path in German (and perc. ciclabile or pista ciclabile in Italian)

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thanks for that. I guess to somebody who speaks the language, it's a bit of a silly question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Radroute" is just a generic term pointing to a major way for bicycles.

In this place near Reschen (South Tyrol) it most likely points towards a stretch of Via Claudia Augusta that follows the valley of the Etsch river towards Meran:
http://www.viaclaudia.org/en/introduction.html

Another map with the route can be found here: https://cycling.waymarkedtrails.org/#route?id=3879552&map=11!46.7027!10.9357